# amdgpu: Unsupported power mode 0 on RENOIR

Tags: boot, amd-graphics

I'm having trouble with my Lenovo T14 (AMD) laptop with a Ryzen 7 running Kubuntu (20.04.3 LTS). Until yesterday everything worked fine. However, yesterday suddenly the laptop froze and I had to turn it off forcefully. When rebooting I got this message on a black screen:

```
[ 3.215831] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: Unsupported power mode 0 on 
RENOIR
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view 
system log, "Systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" 
to boot into default mode.
Drücken Sie die Eingabetaste für Wartungsarbeiten
(oder drücken Sie Ctrl+D um fortzufahren):
```

Booting into default does not work, I end up at the exact same screen within a few seconds. Rebooting resultet in being able to choose OS (since I have only Kubuntu, that does not matter) and then I end up at the same place.

According to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1355957/amdgpu-unsupported-power-profile-mode-0 this is a kernel problem with the 5.11.0 kernel. Mine is 5.11.0-27, so I tried switching to 5.11.0-25, 5.10.0-1044 and even 5.8.0-63:
With 5.11.0-25 and 5.10.0-1044 I have the same result. With 5.8.0-63 I receive a different error message (something about a link not found) but still on the same screen.

Booting into recovery mode doesn't really help. It then shows me a mixed screen with the recovery mode menu overlaid with lines of the 'emergency mode' screen. When typing it seems to react mostly as if I were in the 'emergency mode' screen, but the recovery mode screen also reacts at times...

Booting from a life USB stick (around 6 months old) has worked so far, however, I would not know what to do with that except for reinstalling my system. Which I would like to avoid for now. And if it's a kernel problem, it probably would not help either, would it?

Has anyone an idea what exactly the problem could be and how to resolve that?

Any help is much appreciated.

BTW: I tried the workaround suggested in the link above, but it didn't change anything.

I also realise that shortly before the freeze, I couldn't access some folders on an external drive and firefox had crashed several times for no obvious reason.